# Why does my java program occasionally not respond saving a file with java filechooser?

Tags: java

I'm using Eclipse saving a .wav file and roughly every fourth or fifth time I run the program it saves the file fine. Most times the program itself just hangs and the screen goes black when the file chooser frame should become visible to choose the location of the file. Does anyone know why this would happen occasionally? Eclipse gives no error in the console window and the code builds fine with no errors.
StopRecording and saveFile are are in the Mainframe class
save method is in another recording setup class

```
private void stopRecording() {
    isRecording = false;
    try {
        timer.cancel();
        RecordButton.setText("Record");
        RecordButton.setIcon(iconRecord);
        recorder.stop();
        saveFile();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Mainframe.this, "Error",
                "Error stopping sound recording!",
                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}


private void saveFile() {
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    FileFilter wavFilter = new FileFilter() {
        @Override
        public String getDescription() {
            return "Sound file (*.WAV)";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean accept(File file) {
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                return true;
            } else {
                return file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav");
            }
        }
    };

    fileChooser.setFileFilter(wavFilter);
    fileChooser.setAcceptAllFileFilterUsed(false);

    int userChoice = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(this);
    if (userChoice == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
        saveFilePath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
        if (!saveFilePath.toLowerCase().endsWith(".wav")) {
            saveFilePath += ".wav";
        }

        File wavFile = new File(saveFilePath);

        try {
            recorder.save(wavFile);
            buttonPlay.setEnabled(true);
            Keyup.setEnabled(true);
            Keydown.setEnabled(true);
            btnSave.setEnabled(true);
            getKey.setEnabled(true);
            System.out.print(saveFilePath);

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Mainframe.this, "Error",
                    "Error saving to sound file!",
                    JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void save(File wavFile) throws IOException {
    byte[] audioData = recordBytes.toByteArray();
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(audioData);
    AudioInputStream audioInputStream = new AudioInputStream(bais, format,
            audioData.length / format.getFrameSize());      
    AudioSystem.write(audioInputStream, AudioFileFormat.Type.WAVE, wavFile);

    audioInputStream.close();
    recordBytes.close();
}
```

Comment: Code plz? I'm sure it has something to with that

Comment: Maybe some other process is using the file? Try to account for that possibility. Maybe always write a new file, never overwrite.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've solved it. It was actually hanging on stopping the recording thread not saving the file.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling  recorder.save(wavFile); twice.  Try calling it just once.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to take one of them out calling it once makes no difference. The program still hangs.